# Rails - creating a keyholder for a user account - issue with access restriction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions

I want to create an app where the users can nominate a 'keyholder' who can have read-only access to their account. I am using Devise for user authentication. Additionally, I have boolean fields in the database to determine if the user logged in is a keyholder, and also there is an 'access_id' integer field that equals the user id of the user that they are allowed to access.

I am trying to create access restrictions so that only the user, or their keyholder, can access their account (and not just anyone typing in their user number into the address bar). I will later restrict the access further based on the user role, however I am currently getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#myaccount 
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

It is referring to this code I added to the application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :correct_user


    private

      def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @keyholder = User.find(params[:access_id])

        redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user==@user||@keyholder
      end
end
```

It is giving the error for this line:

```
@keyholder = User.find(params[:access_id])
```

Also, here is the code for the #myaccount action in the users controller:

```
def myaccount
    if user_signed_in?
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Please login to view your account'
    end
  end
```

I have the access_id set to 0 for all records in the database, except the keyholders, where the access id equals the user_id that they are allowed to access.

Can anyone help me with this? I just want the right people to be able to access the accounts, before I restrict permissions further. Thanks!!

UPDATE:

If I change the code to this:

```
def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])

        redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user==@user
      end
```

then the user can only access their own account, which is fine, but I need a way of the keyholder being able to access the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `@keyholder = User.find(params[:access_id])` causes an error because you are using `find`.  You can change that to

```
@keyholder = User.find_by_id(params[:access_id])
#or
@keyholder = User.where(id: params[:access_id]).first
```

which will both return `nil` when they can't find a keyholder.

UPDATE:

Assuming that `access_id` contains the id of the user that can access @user, you can check using the following

```
if @user && current_user.id == @user.id
  # don't redirect
elsif @keyholder && current_user.id == @keyholder.access_id
  # don't redirect
else
  # redirect
end
```

simplifying that, we have

```
unless (@user && current_user.id == @user.id) || (@keyholder && current_user.id == @keyholder.access_id)
  # redirect
end
```

Comment: Can you explain, why `find` doesn't work, but `find_by_id` will?

Comment: That isn't giving any errors now, but I can't get the correct syntax for allowing the keyholder to access the user account - please can you help me? I've added the first suggestion you gave for the keyholder, but need a seperate line to actually give the access - i.e.: redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user==(@user ||=@keyholder) any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: i actually didn't get how you are setting the keyholder for a particular user. can you show some specific examples in your question.

Comment: Basically, I want the correct version of this line: redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.id== (@user.id ||= @keyholder.access_id) but I can't get the right syntax - any help would be much appreciated! I'm just trying to get the access sorted before I start on how to set up the keyholder. I've manually updated the database with the right data. The keyholder is a user with the 'keyholder' boolean field set to true, and the 'access_id' field equal to the user_id of the user whose account they can access.

Comment: ah that should be `if current_user.id != @user.id && current_user.id != @keyholder.id`

Comment: That allows the user to access their own account, but not the account of the person they are the keyholder for - it gives this error: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id . I think I'm being a bit confusing. There is a user with an id of 1, and another user - a keyholder - with an access_id of 1. That second user, the keyholder, should be able to access the account of the user 1, but no-one else should be able to. How do I do that?

Comment: You got me nearly all the way to the answer, thanks so much for your help! Figured it out - the line I wanted was: unless (@user && current_user.id == @user.id) || ((current_user.access_id==@user.id)&&(current_user.id==@user.access_id))
          redirect_to root_path
        end    - Thanks!!